# How to integrate rest api with front end website/app?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I already built out my restful api for logging in and registering, my question is how do I now use this api in my website? Isn't the point of an api to return json to consume? If i were to put a res.redirect() then wouldn't that make the api useless for later on when i want to use the api for say an iOS app?

```
router.post('/login', async (request, response) => {

        // validate 
        const {error} = loginValidation(request.body)
        if (error) return response.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)


        const {email, password} = request.body


        // check if email doesn't exist
        const user = await pool.query('SELECT id, email, password FROM users WHERE email = $1 LIMIT 1', [email])
        if(user.rowCount == 0) return response.status(400).send('Wrong email or password')

        // password is correct; move on to validating password
        const id = user.rows[0].id
        const storedEmail = user.rows[0].email
        const storedPassword = user.rows[0].password
        const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(request.body.password, storedPassword)
        if(!validPass) return response.status(400).send('Wrong email or password')

        // create and send token to client
        const token = jwt.sign({_id: id}, "SOMESECRET")
        response.header('auth-token', token).send(token)


    })
```

Comment: You can call your API from your website, no need to redirect anywhere. [Start here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Basic_concepts)

Answer (score 0):

You could try these ways:

1. Make API calls from web clients(i.e. web browsers) with Javascript.
2. Set up a web server and make API calls from the server.

Comment: Yeah so i'm looking into Axios, i was wondering when getting data from a https client side, what's the best method of then injecting that data into my html elements/tags?

Comment: You could manipulate DOM with Javascript or use frameworks such as jQuery and other SPA libraries for easier solutions.